# Avoid turbofish type anotation on collect() to Result<Vec<_>, _>

Tags: rust

I would like to use the `collect()` an iterator of `Result<T, E>`s into a `Vec<T>` and early-return in case any of the elements in the iterator was an error. So, something like this:

```rust
use std::error::Error;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let input = ""; // Snip real input
    let games: Vec<Game> = input.lines().map(parse_game).collect()?;
    println!("parsed {} games", games.len());
    Ok(())
}

struct Game;

fn parse_game(_s: &str) -> Result<Game, Box<dyn Error>> {
    Ok(Game)
}
```

([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e3d07179e552de20a05ef7234dc3fe8a), and yes, the code is inspired on Advent of Code 2023 day 2)

But this doesn't work, it fails to compile with the error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/main.rs:5:58
  |
5 |     let games: Vec<Game> = input.lines().map(parse_game).collect()?;
  |                                                          ^^^^^^^ cannot infer type of the type parameter `B` declared on the method `collect`
  |
help: consider specifying the generic argument
  |
5 |     let games: Vec<Game> = input.lines().map(parse_game).collect::<Vec<_>>()?;
  |                                                                 ++++++++++
```

If I add the type annotation to use the correct [`impl FromIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html#impl-FromIterator%3CResult%3CA,+E%3E%3E-for-Result%3CV,+E%3E) on `collect()`, it works:

```rust
let games: Vec<Game> = input.lines().map(parse_game).collect::<Result<_, _>>()?;
```

([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=417505aeb7a48f322c5f311d3ce0ca87))

But I don't understand why this turbofish type annotation of `::<Result<_, _>>` is necessary. And I find it quite superfluous and noisy.

I would have expected the Rust compiler to know that `parse_game` returns `Result`s, and that if I want to collect into a `Vec<Game>` (as specified by the `games` variable type) and I'm early-returning with the `?` operator on a function that returns `Result` (`main()`), then that `collect()` call should be returning `Result` too and thus wouldn't need an explicit type annotation.

So, is there a way to get rid of this turbofish type annotation? Or some other idiomatic way of expressing this?

Comment: Yeah this is something I've wondered too. Rust seems very timid when it comes to inferring types around the `?`, and it results in a lot of extra annotations (especially, but not exclusively, around `.collect()` calls)

Comment: It's because (IIUC) `expr?` in a function returning a `Result` only signifies that `Result: FromResidual<<Expr as Try>::Residual>`, which is not enough to deduce the type of `Expr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are ways to get rid of the turbofish, but you're not going to like them. First way is to use an intermediate variable.

```rust
let games_result: Result<_, _> = input.lines().map(parse_game).collect();
let games: Vec<Game> = games_result?;
```

Second way is to use `collect`'s internal trait function, `FromIterator::from_iter`.

```rust
let games: Vec<Game> = Result::from_iter(input.lines().map(parse_game))?;
```

The first one doesn't offer any improvements over the turbofish in noisiness, and the second one loses the functional style of `collect`.

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a better way of avoiding the turbofish for `collect`. However, the itertools crate offers [`try_collect`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.try_collect), which does what you want.

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;
let games: Vec<Game> = input.lines().map(parse_game).try_collect()?;
```

Comment: Instead of an intermediate variable, you could use an intermediate function and elide the explicit variable type in favor of the explicit function signature. Sometimes that can feel less icky, even though it's effectively the same.

Comment: @drewtato "but you're not going to like them", wow have we met before? because you totally hit the nail on the head there :)
This is a great answer; i'd never have thought about the explicit `Result::from_iter()` inversion. And i'm marking it as accepted for now because the `itertools` solution, although not ideal, actually does what i wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @MeetTitan, that's also a very good suggestion. I like it [how the code looks](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3401bf83ab553e2b45cbc3383e95e193), as the extracted function needs an explicit return value anyways, and it allows al variable types to be inferred correctly. You could make write this another answer; i think some people could find it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

I just learned that there's a [proposal for `Iterator::try_collect()`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/94047) that does exactly this and can be used on Rust nightly as an unstable feature:

```rust
#![feature(iterator_try_collect)]
// And then:
let games: Vec<_> = input.lines().map(parse_game).try_collect()?;
```

([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9c43882e65358bfb5ce242c9001517bc))

This is not applicable for folks that want to use only stable Rust (like me), but could be a handy feature if you're already on nightly.